# Harmonic Function Cauchy implication

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $b$ be harmonic real valued on unit disk. Then I wish to prove that $\int_\alpha b =0$.

I know that there exists $f$ holomorphic such that $\Re(f)=b$, and I know from Cauchys result that $\int_\alpha f=0$. But then how can I reach the conclusion from here. Can you give a hint.

Here $\alpha$ p.w $C^1$.

Comment: The time to describe $\alpha $ is in the first line. What is it by the way? A closed contour in the unit disc?

Comment: Yes it is, a closed contour.